# Extract the most recent values from appended .CSV in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, loops, csv, timer

I have a .csv file which is appended with 3 new values in the row below the previous set:

```
dlmwrite('MyFile.csv', [MyValue,MyValue2,MyValue3], '-append');
```

This happens every minute. It happens indefinitely because of a timer i.e it accumulates data over time:

How can I continually copy over the 60 most recent sets of values from the file and store them in a new csv file, say `MyFile2`.The row number of the .csv file is increasing by 1 with every minute. i.e 60 values stored in 60 minutes but I may have 100 values and want to extract the latest 60 for another file.

Image of the CSV file - 2nd column is time in HOURS:MINUTES without the : separator (ignore the lapse in time between rows 38 and 39 or any lapses elsewhere):

[image]

Note: MyValue is added to the file every minute because the script is run every 60 seconds from another script. I.e there is no internal timer in the main script:

```
Period = 60; % Update period in seconds

tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
    'TimerFcn', 'TESTINGFINAL');

start(tim)

stop(tim) 

runtmp = fullfile('MyScriptLocation','MyScript');
run(runtmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this continuously while running I'd suggest some sort of circular buffer arrangement so you always have the last 60 values in memory.  This will be easier than trying to work out the current length of your continuously logging file.   Basic idea (minus the actual timing code):

```
% initialising buffer
MyValue1 = zeros(60,1);

while true  % for certain values of true 

 % these go once a minute
 mv1 = myfunc1(inputs); 
 MyValue1 = [MyValue1(2:end); mv1];
 dlmwrite('MyFile.csv', [mv1], '-append');

 % this goes less frequently, I presume
 filename = [datestr(now,30),'.csv'];  % dynamic filename
 dlmwrite(filename, MyValue1);

end
```

This way you have both your continuously logging file (updated every minute), and a series of smaller files containing what were the last 60 values at the time they were written (updated hourly, or on some other trigger, as required).

With your timer, one way of doing this would appear to be to keep a simple counter of how many times the acquisition script has run and then use the `mod` function to check for when this hits a multiple of 60.

Comment: I've edited my thread to include more info about the timer acting on the script. It's actually updating the values by running the script within a separate script. Would I not be best to just use the file dimensions for this? How could I do it.

Comment: What does 'mv1' represent?

Comment: Hi - in this version, `mv1` would be your single value taken from some data acquisition process or calculated from some function - MyValue1 is a buffer containing the latest 60 of these.  I do think it would be easier to do it this way rather than trying to work out file dimensions, especially as your continuous file grows. Will edit.

Comment: I have 3 values though. i.e mv1 is more like mv1,mv2,mv3 and these 3 are appended together in the same row of the .csv file each minute. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but I do have an idea if I understand you correctly. This means you probably want to run Matlab 24/7? Or at least non-stop for a certain amount of time? If so, you could try out the command `clock`, it shows and stores the system time. In your case

`time=clock;` 
where 
`time(4)` holds the hour. So as soon as this parameter changes, you should open your .csv file and save the last 60 values.

However, doing it this way I think is highly energy-consuming. And sadly Matlab does not have a `sleep` command like for example Unix does, so maybe it would be interesting to look into running this program in another programming language?

Please provide me with comments and feedback since I see that this is not a complete answer (yet)!

Comment: I've edited my thread to include more info about the timer acting on the script, please have a look. It's actually updating the values by running the script within a separate script.  I'm taking data from a web source for MyValue (imagine stock/weather information) so that's where the time is appended from in the file.